# Xcode 6.1 not showing launch image on ios 8.1

Tags: objective-c, iphone-5, xcode6.1, ios8.1

Recently I updated my Xcode version to 6.1 and ios to 8.1 . Now while launching my app on my iphone 5 its not showing me my launch image instead its showing a blank white screen only.

Selected app and launch image section is shown in image. Please tell me where am I going wrong?

[image: Display image for settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch images are now managed in a xib file rather than an xcassests file. This is because there are more devices all with different screen sizes and Xcode has to be able to manage them.

Set up a xib file called LaunchScreen.xib with just one view in it's hierarchy and with no owner. Put your images in that view. Then in the general settings for your iOS target change Lauch Screen File to LaunchScreen.xib

Comment: This is a good alternative, but if you still want to use xcassests and launch images, you can just delete the text in the `Launch Screen File` box so that it's left empty and the xcassests images will show on launch instead of the `LaunchScreen.xib`.

Comment: I did this exact thing and I'm not getting my XIB on my iOS 8 devices.  I guess I'll have to add a new question.

Comment: Do a clean build... that helped me and I was able to get my splash images back

Answer (score 0):

If your Splash Screen not showing in Ios 8.1 then you have to check only for ios 8 or latter 
just follow this....

1- click on Launch Image Source (Arrow) (You show in screenshot)

2- open Inspector and Check ios 8 or latter.

3- Add our Splash Images accordingly

Thanks